# Why is my If function that is checking the background color of a cell not working?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, background-color

First off, the code:

```
If ws.Cells(.Value + 1, 28).Interior.ColorIndex = 16 Then Mark1.LU1DISCOCHECK = True Else Mark1.LU1DISCOCHECK = False
```

The cell is the correct color, yet the if statement is not changing the checkbox at all.
I'm not too familiar with color indexes but based on what I know, this should be working just fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Was the fill applied manually, or is it from conditional formatting?  If the second one, you need to check `DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`

Comment: It was from a different code, not conditional formatting.
`If Mark1.LU1DISCOCHECK = True Then ws.Cells(.Value + 1, 28).Interior.ColorIndex = 16 Else ws.Cells(.Value + 1, 28).Interior.ColorIndex = 2`

Comment: Do i need to add the displayformat to both codes?

Comment: this worked perfectly. please post as an answer so i can upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier like this:

```vb
Mark1.LU1DISCOCHECK = (ws.Cells(.Value + 1, 28).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 16)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> If ws.Cells(.Value + 1, 28).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 200, 150)
> Then Mark1.LU1DISCOCHECK = True Else Mark1.LU1DISCOCHECK = False

Or:

> If ws.Cells(.Value + 1, 28).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
> Then Mark1.LU1DISCOCHECK = True Else Mark1.LU1DISCOCHECK = False